# How to manage CSS in an MVC application

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

Its my first time here. My english is not really good, I hope to don't "seem" so rude.

Im working with an MVC 5 application using the default bootstrap.css styles.

The problem is that I want to add some personalized css code to my proyect but its not working.

I want to disable an `@Html.ActionLink` via CSS. (I dont want jQuery or JavaScript).
After some readings I found this:

In css file:

```
.linkdisabled{
   cursor:text;
}
```

In my view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkname", "action", "controller", new { @class = "linkdisabled" })
```

The problem is that I cant add any code to the bootstrap.css (I can add and Im doing at the end of file but its not working)

Comment: Have you included your custom CSS file at the end of your CSS links? Use the JavaScript debugger (F12 in Chrome and Firefox) to see if your class is ever applied (and possibly overridden).

Comment: Instead of modifying the bootstrap file, make your own file "site.css" alongside it.  Then include your file in the header tag in your layout.

Comment: Jonesy's solution is better but if you wan't to avoid creating more files, you can use inline css by wrapping it in <style type="text/css"> ... </style> in your <head> section

Comment: @Jonesy, there is no class that named "linkdisabled" in bootstrap file. But this is not your mistake, question is a bit unclear...

Comment: My point was, don't modify or add to the bootstrap file for any reason, rather create your own

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working. Adding my own css class.
I had to add mycss.css to the content folder. Then I added the path route to my css in App_Star folder -> BundleConfig.cs
And in the end I had to add @Scripts.Render("path") into the layout view.

Thanks everybody !!

Answer (score 2):

use following correct overload method

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "linkname", 
    "action", 
    "controller", 
    null, 
    new { @class = "linkdisabled" }
)
```

[ActionLink correct overload method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```